# How to unblur the image using css

Tags: css

I am trying to unblur the text for my image which i am unable to do it below is my css for that image

```css
img[Attributes Style] {
   width: 109px;
   height: 19px;
   border-top-width: 0px;
   border-right-width: 0px;
   border-bottom-width: 0px;
   border-left-width: 0px;
   border-top-style: solid;
   border-right-style: solid;
   border-bottom-style: solid;
   border-left-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300" width="109" height="19" 
style="vertical-align:top;" border="0">
```

I am unable to edit that css after opening the inspector i tried with `opacity :1` not working

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeikG.png)

Comment: it would be better if you added an image of what you getting now and what you need

Comment: currently i am able to view the blured image and i want to unblur the image

Comment: The example you are giving here, your image is shrunken instead of blurred. If that's what is causing you issue, increase it's size and it will be fine

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but bluring is the process of removing information from image, so to "unblur" it you need somehow restore lost information, which is in general case just impossible, though some people experiment with neural networks and got quite nice results

Answer (score 0):

The problem is opacity doesn't make the image blurred. It is used to adjust the transparency of an image.
What you should you use is
  filter: blur(1px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);

Increase the pixel value and it will add blureness to your image, increasing the pixel value will make it more blurred

Comment: but i am unable to edit it and what is the css that i need to use to make it unblur

Comment: Blurred or shrunked?

Comment: added the image for your reference

Comment: The height of the image is very small but the width is high, that's why it looks shrunken 
set    height: 100px;

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you provided for the image, I am wondering...

The image itself is blured, rigth? I mean it's not blurred by code?

Also I can't see anything about blur in the css you provided.

If my assumption is right, you won't be able to unblur this with css.

We'll need to get another image.

Otherwise, @Faizal's answer is correct.

```
-webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
```

Here's an example on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/dzomba/pen/npdfh